# Numpy: using np.pad() for an RGB image causing "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4,3) (4,4,5)" error

Tags: numpy

I have a function `color_image_padding` that takes an **RGB image** and adds one layer of zeros padding to the borders.  The image has dimensions `(Width, Height, 3)`, with 3 representing the 3 color channels.

My code is:

```
   import numpy as np

   def color_image_padding(image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
       return np.pad(image, pad_width=1)
```

I'm seeing this error:

```
"operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4,3) (4,4,5)"
```

It's probably the color channels that are causing this error.  Doesn't `np.pad` split the image into 3 matrices and add the zero padding accordingly?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

**EDIT**

See comments below...  It turns out that the generalized function `image_padding()` was throwing an error message because some greyscale images (i.e. 2D Numpy matrices) were passed in.  Here's a minimal example:

```
bar = np.ones((1, 3))
bar.ndim
2

def image_padding(image: np.ndarray, amt: int) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.pad(image, pad_width=((amt, amt), (amt, amt), (0, 0)))

image_padding(bar, 2)
```

Full Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8116/4065018867.py in <module>
----> 1 img(bar, 3)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8116/1455868751.py in img(image, amt)
      1 def img(image, amt):
----> 2     return np.pad(image, pad_width=((amt, amt), (amt, amt), (0, 0)))

<__array_function__ internals> in pad(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py in pad(array, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
    741 
    742     # Broadcast to shape (array.ndim, 2)
--> 743     pad_width = _as_pairs(pad_width, array.ndim, as_index=True)
    744 
    745     if callable(mode):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py in _as_pairs(x, ndim, as_index)
    516     # Converting the array with `tolist` seems to improve performance
    517     # when iterating and indexing the result (see usage in `pad`)
--> 518     return np.broadcast_to(x, (ndim, 2)).tolist()
    519 
    520 

<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_to(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    409            [1, 2, 3]])
    410     """
--> 411     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
    412 
    413 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    346                          'negative')
    347     extras = []
--> 348     it = np.nditer(
    349         (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
    350         op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2)  and requested shape (2,2)
```

Testing whether the image is greyscale or color resolves the issue:

```
def image_padding(image: np.ndarray, amt: int) -> np.ndarray:
    if image.ndim == 2:
        return np.pad(image, pad_width=(amt, amt))
    elif img.ndim == 3:
        return np.pad(image, pad_width=((amt, amt), (amt, amt), (0, 0)))
```

Comment: You didn't spend much time reading the `pad` docs, did you?  `pad_width`' is "Number of values padded to the edges of **each axis**." - that includes the channels axis if given simple scalar!

Comment: @hpaulj - I changed `pad_width` to:  `pad_width=(1, 1, 1)` to handle the 3 color channels (which is what I *think* the docs are suggesting).  But, now, I'm seeing:  `operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,)  and requested shape (3,2)`.

Comment: I think the padding should be a tuple of tuples, e.g. `((1,1),(1,1),(0,0))`, that is a value both directions for each of the 3 axes.  (assuming you want to pad the height and width, but not the channels.

Comment: `np.pad` works an an n-dimensional array.  It does not "know" anything special about "channels", that's just another dimension.  It isn't a 'image processing" function, but rather a general purpose `numpy` one.

Comment: Yes, the tuple of tuples - `((1,1),(1,1),(0,0))` - works beautifully.  Thank you for your help and for the explanation!

Comment: @hpaulj - let's assume I want to be able to configure the amount of padding around the image.  To do so, I add a parameter called `amt_padding`.  The return statement then becomes:  `return np.pad(image, pad_width=((amt_padding, amt_padding), (amt_padding, amt_padding), (0, 0)))`.  I'm seeing that same `operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2)  and requested shape (2,2)` error.  Is this caused by the `(0, 0)` tuple in `pad_width`?

Comment: Show the actual error - with traceback - in your question (not a comment).  Is this error in `np.pad`, or in code that uses the result?

Comment: I don't have access to the full traceback.  The only error that's exposed to me is `operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2)  and requested shape (2,2)`.  Yes, this error is caused by `np.pad()`.  My function, which is  simply an extension of the original function, takes two parameters - a matrix representing the image and the number of pads - then returns:  `return np.pad(image, pad_width=((amt_padding, amt_padding), (amt_padding, amt_padding), (0, 0)))`.  It looks like it's a shape issue with the `pad_width` parameter, but I don't know why.

Comment: `numpy` does not raise an error with wording like "operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes".  The only thing that a web search turns up is in some package called `skyfield`.  The error may be caused by the padded array, but it does not occur IN `np.pad`.

Comment: The `operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2)  and requested shape (2,2)` error is the same one we saw with the original function before passing the tuple of tuples to the `pad_width` parameter.  Could it be that the parameters I passed to `pad_width` are causing an issue?  Structurally, do they look correct?  Again, I'm simply trying to *generalize the original function* by allowing a user to pass a variable number of pads (instead of only a single pad).  I thought it was as simple as introducing a parameter, but maybe not...

Comment: It turns out the function was taking an `image` argument that's **either** greyscale or color.  So, the approach we discussed works for color, but not for greyscale.  Adding some logic to test `image.ndim` resolves the error message (which did come from Numpy - I got access to the test cases and will edit this post for completeness.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this reproduces your error - using the three term `pad_width` on a 2d array:

ok with 3d:

```
In [194]: x = np.ones((5,5,3),int)
In [196]: amt_padding=1;np.pad(x, pad_width=((amt_padding, amt_padding), (amt_padding, amt_padding), (0, 0))).shape
Out[196]: (7, 7, 3)
```

but if the array is 2d:

```
In [197]: amt_padding=1;np.pad(x[:,:,0], pad_width=((amt_padding, amt_padding), (amt_padding, amt_padding), (0, 0)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [197], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 amt_padding=1;np.pad(x[:,:,0], pad_width=((amt_padding, amt_padding), (amt_padding, amt_padding), (0, 0)))

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in pad(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py:743, in pad(array, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
    740     raise TypeError('`pad_width` must be of integral type.')
    742 # Broadcast to shape (array.ndim, 2)
--> 743 pad_width = _as_pairs(pad_width, array.ndim, as_index=True)
    745 if callable(mode):
    746     # Old behavior: Use user-supplied function with np.apply_along_axis
    747     function = mode

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py:518, in _as_pairs(x, ndim, as_index)
    514     raise ValueError("index can't contain negative values")
    516 # Converting the array with `tolist` seems to improve performance
    517 # when iterating and indexing the result (see usage in `pad`)
--> 518 return np.broadcast_to(x, (ndim, 2)).tolist()

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in broadcast_to(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py:411, in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    366 @array_function_dispatch(_broadcast_to_dispatcher, module='numpy')
    367 def broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=False):
    368     """Broadcast an array to a new shape.
    369 
    370     Parameters
   (...)
    409            [1, 2, 3]])
    410     """
--> 411     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py:348, in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    345     raise ValueError('all elements of broadcast shape must be non-'
    346                      'negative')
    347 extras = []
--> 348 it = np.nditer(
    349     (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
    350     op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')
    351 with it:
    352     # never really has writebackifcopy semantics
    353     broadcast = it.itviews[0]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2)  and requested shape (2,2)
```

It's passing the task to `np.nditer` (via `broadcast_to`), which is raising the error.  That would account for why I've never seen it before.  I've explored `nditer` some, but it's not something I regularly use or recommend to others.

The `_as_pairs` expands `widths` like

```
In [206]: np.lib.arraypad._as_pairs(1,3, as_index=True)
Out[206]: ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1))

In [207]: np.lib.arraypad._as_pairs(((1,),(2,),(3,)),3, as_index=True)
Out[207]: [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  Thanks for your help tracking this down.